# Iterate over all possible states with only one change

Tags: algorithm, math

let's say we have two variables L and S

L: length of any sequence (count of items in any sequence)

S: number of possible states for any item

And imagine we have a set of all possible sequences with these two variables.
For example:

```
L=3, S=2

All Possible Sequences : S is 2 so we can have 0 and 1 for any item
0,1,0 0,0,0 1,0,0 1,1,0 1,1,1 0,1,1 0,0,1 1,0,1
```

Now the problem that I have is: Is there any way to iterate on the set of all possible sequences by having only one change at every step? you can see a sample in the example I wrote above. (I have calculated them by hand). at every step, we have only one change (one item increase or decrease by 1)

I need a none recursive function or method (in math or programming) to get the i'th state from an L, S set with that rule(one change at every index change)

Comment: It seesm, you are looking for *Gray codes*, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Idea:

Let's say that every digit in a position is changed every(right-to-left) 1, S, S * S, S * S * S ... iteration.

And every of 2 * S change it will be mapped according to (0 ... S - 1, S - 1 ... 0):

```
0 -> 0
...
S - 1 -> S - 1
S ->     S - 1
S + 1 -> S - 2
...
2 * S - 1 -> 0
```

Since S - 1 and S produce the same result will guarantee that a digit remains the same when a digit in previous position is changed.

C# implementation:

```
public static int[] Func(long n, int S, int L)
{
    var num = new int[L];

    for (int i = L - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var x = (int)(n % (2 * S));
        num[i] = x < S ? x : 2 * S - x - 1;
        n /= S;
    }

    return num;
}
```

Iterating through a whole sequence:

```
    int S = 3, L = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Pow(S, L); i++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(String.Join(' ', Func(i, S, L)));
    }
```

The output:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 2
0 1 1
0 1 0
0 2 0
0 2 1
0 2 2
1 2 2
1 2 1
1 2 0
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 0 2
1 0 1
1 0 0
2 0 0
2 0 1
2 0 2
2 1 2
2 1 1
2 1 0
2 2 0
2 2 1
2 2 2
```

Can try here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5AzYWr

Comment: Thanks a lot, Do you have any idea to implement this method in a way that we can use it without exponential complexity? you know I need to use this for large L values like L = 10^6 , S < 10 and i vary between the space

Comment: @MohamadAliZeraatkar, actually it's simple - we don't need to pre-count base for each position, updated the answer and the fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/5AzYWr

Comment: Of course, you will need smth bigger than standard long to specify an index, though the alg is linear and the idea should be also clear I hope.

Comment: May I ask you how did you come up with this solution?

Comment: Good question :) First you're trying to found a pattern by generating elements manually (or brute force alg) and then can note that every digit is going from 0 to S - 1 and back (except the higher one, it does just a single 0 -> S - 1 route). Having the sequence generated it's easier to see the rule. So each digit follows the same cycle (0 -> S - 1 -> 0) but with a "delay", making one step for a second digit every S iterations, S * S for 3rtd etc.. And that's the solution in fact. By n and index we known how many ticks were made, hence we can count a position in a cycle.

Comment: Btw, it's not a linear solution, but rather O(L * size_t(n)), which is close for standard integer indexes. Though for L~10^6, it's about 300k bytes required to store index, and it will takes hours, but I have no idea how to improve further.

Comment: Thank you, and do you have any idea about a similar algorithm that changes numbers at all positions uniformly? as you can see in your solution the last number (right end) changes about every index change and the first number at the left changes much less.

Comment: smth like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5AzYWr ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems, that you are looking for [Gray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)

**C# code**

```
public static IEnumerable<int[]> GrayCodes(int length, int radix) {
  if (length < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length));
  if (radix < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(radix));

  if (0 == length || 0 == radix)
    yield break;

  static int digit(long n, int radix, int i) =>
    (int)(Math.Floor(n / Math.Pow(radix, i)) % radix);

  double count = Math.Pow(radix, length);

  long max = count > long.MaxValue ? long.MaxValue : (long)count;

  for (long i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
    int[] result = new int[length];
    int shift = 0;

    for (int j = length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      var x = (digit(i, radix, j) + shift) % radix;

      shift += radix - x;
      result[length - j - 1] = x;
    }

    yield return result;
  }
}
```

**Demo**

```
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GrayCodes(2, 3)
  .Select(g => string.Join(" ", g)));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 2
1 0
1 1
2 1
2 2
2 0
```

If you want to *flatten* the sequence, add `SelectMany`:

```
var report = string.Join(", ", GrayCodes(2, 3).SelectMany(g => g));

Console.WriteLine(report);

Console.WriteLine();

// Your case, length = 3, radix = 2
report = string.Join(", ", GrayCodes(3, 2).SelectMany(g => g));

Console.WriteLine(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0

0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
```

**Edit:** If "only one change at every step" means not only "in one position" (so `2 1 0` -> `2 1 2` is allowed) but in "in one position **and** by +1 or -1 only" you can still use Gray code. The algorithm (let me name it "To and Fro") is below.

1. Start from all zeroes `0...000`
2. Start *incrementing* `n`th digit while it's possible: `0..00 -> 0..01 -> .. -> 0..00dn`
3. Increment `n-1`th digit and start *decrementing* `n`th digit: `0..00dn -> 0..01dn -> ... 0..011 -> 0..10`
4. Increment `n-1`th digit and start *incrementing* `n`th digit: `0..10 -> 0..20 -> 0..021 -> ...0..2dn`
5. On `0..0dn-1dn` increment `n-2`th index and start decrementing `n`th etc.

Demo

```
# start from 000
    000 -> 001 -> 002 -> 
# increment n-1 th digit, decrementing n-th
 -> 012 -> 011 -> 010 ->    
# increment n-1 th digit, incrementing n-th
 -> 020 -> 021 -> 022 -> 
# increment n-2 th digit, decrementing n-th
 -> 122 -> 121 -> 120 ->
# decrement n-1 th digit, incrementing n-th
 -> 110 -> 111 -> 112 ->
# decrement n-1 th digit, decrementing n-th
 -> 102 -> 101 -> 100 -> 
# increment n-2 th digit, incrementing n-th
 -> 200 -> 201 -> 202 ->
# increment n-1 th digit, decrementing n-th
 -> 212 -> 211 -> 210 -> 
# increment n-1 th digit, incrementing n-th
 -> 220 -> 221 -> 222
```

**C# Code:** (Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k1swXi))

```
public static IEnumerable<int[]> GrayCodes(int length, int radix) {
  if (length < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length));
  if (radix < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(radix));

  if (0 == length || 0 == radix)
    yield break;

  int[] signs = Enumerable.Repeat(1, length).ToArray();
  int[] current = new int[length];

  for (bool keep = true; keep; ) {
    yield return current.ToArray();

    keep = false;

    for (int i = current.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      int d = current[i] + signs[i];

      if (d >= 0 && d < radix) {
        current[i] = d;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < signs.Length; ++j)
          signs[j] = -signs[j];
        
        keep = true;

        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GrayCodes(3, 3)
  .Select(line => string.Join(" ", line))));
```

**Outcome:**

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 2
0 1 1
0 1 0
0 2 0
0 2 1
0 2 2
1 2 2
1 2 1
1 2 0
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 0 2
1 0 1
1 0 0
2 0 0
2 0 1
2 0 2
2 1 2
2 1 1
2 1 0
2 2 0
2 2 1
2 2 2
```

Comment: thank you. but it seems this is not the solution. as you can see we have 1 0 after 1 2, 0 increased by 2

Comment: @MohamadAli Zeraatkar: if you want to allow just `+1 / -1` change at a *single* position only, you can try Gray code modification (fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k1swXi).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't go to get familiar with gray codes yet, but you know I need to use this for large L values like L = 10^6 , S < 10 and i varies between the space. so I need an algorithm with low time complexity. it means .Do you have any idea to implement this method in a way that we can use it without exponential complexity?

Comment: @MohamadAli Zeraatkar: the algorithm itself is efficient (linear), however the *complete answer* is *huge*: its size is `S ^ L = pow(S, L)` even if `S = 2`, `S ^ L` is a number with `300000` zeroes (when `L ~ 1e6`). That's why it's impossible to enumerate the answer - the required tie is bigger then age of the Universe

Answer (score 0):

### The Math

There may be multiple answers, I see Gray codes in the other answer, but this is my own solution. Examples are given in decimals (S=10), as I think decimals are easier to understand than binaries. But the method works for any values of S.

For 2 digits decimals (L=2, S=10), I can have:

00, 01, 02, 03, ... 09, 19, 18, 17, 16, ... 10, 20, 21, 22, ...

That is, after 09, instead of 10, we just go to 19 instead, and start counting backwards to 18, 17, ... 10. Then we go to 20, and repeat:

20, ... 29, 39, ... 30, 40, ... 49, 59, ...

Ultimately we will reach 90:
30, 40, ... 50, 60, ... 70, 80, ... 90

But we cannot go to 100, because that involves 2 digits that are changed. But we can use the same trick of counting backwards:

090, 190, 191, ... 199, 189, 188, ... 180, 170, 171, ... 179, 169, ...

### The Function

In Python. Explanation as comments in code.

```
def f(n, l, s):
    # Get all digits of n. 
    # Example for decimals (s=10), if n = 143, digits = [1, 4, 3]
    digits = []
    cur_n = n
    for i in range(l):
        cur_digit = cur_n%s 
        digits.append(cur_digit)
        cur_n = int(cur_n / s)
    digits.reverse() # digits = [1, 4, 3]

    # Continuing the same decimals example if n = 143, the output should be 153.
    # Explanation below. We first copy the digits.
    output_digits = list(digits)

    # First digit is the same.
    output_digits[0] = digits[0]

    # For each digit
    for i in range(len(digits) - 1):
        digit=digits[i]
        next_digit = digits[i+1]

        # If it is an odd number
        if digit%2 == 1:
            # Then the next_output_digit is 9 - next_digit
            next_output_digit = s - 1 - next_digit
        else:
            # Else, the next_output_digit is the same as next_digit
            next_output_digit = next_digit
        output_digits[i+1] = next_output_digit

    # Convert [1, 5, 3] to ["1", "5", "3"]
    output_digits_string = [str(digit) for digit in output_digits]
    # Convert to "153"
    output_string = "".join(output_digits_string)
    # Finally, return output_string
    return int(output_string)
```

To test the algorithm, run these 2 examples:

```
for i in range(199): print(f(i,3,10)) # Decimals, 3 digits, first 199 values
for i in range(8): print(f(i,3,2)) # Binaries, 3 digits, all 8 values
```

Comment: Thank you. but I tried the code for L= 4,S = 3 . for n=8 it outputs 0022 and n=9 the output become 0120